# How to disable forgotten Master password in frozen Samsung Evo 850?

Tags: hard-drive, security, ssd, passwords, sata

This is `hdparm` > `Security` section result :

```
Security:
    Master password revision code = 22616
         supported
         enabled
    not     locked
         frozen
    not     expired: security count
    supported: enhanced erase
    Security level high
    2min for SECURITY ERASE UNIT. 8min for ENHANCED SECURITY ERASE UNIT.
Logical Unit WWN Device Identifier: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
      NAA        : 5
      IEEE OUI    : 002538
      Unique ID    : xxxxxxxxx
Device Sleep:
      DEVSLP Exit Timeout (DETO): 50 ms (drive)
      Minimum DEVSLP Assertion Time (MDAT): 30 ms (drive)
Checksum: correct
```

Beside that, this is my laptop Bios security page image (Lenovo Flex 2) :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ysk6f.jpg

There's no any problem with full wipe. I don't need SSD data because I've already access them without any problem and backed them up some days ago.

Every time I turn on my laptop it always asks me password and I have to enter it to use my SSD. I do know my `user` password but I forgot `Master` password. Please tell me about current state of SSD (`frozen`/`lock`) I really don't know anything about these terms. Please help me to disable Master password.

Comment: Given the purpose of a master password, why do you think there is an easy way around ???

Comment: @SolarMike I think should be a solution even though accompany with a forced full wipe. I've already backed up my data. Still no easy way?

Comment: @Rainyday I would try and Set  the User Password to a new one, and see if you can use the new password to unlock the HDD. If that doesn't work, then it's likely that you indeed need to wipe the disk completely.

Comment: @LPChip Yesterday I did this exactly. I changed 'User' password and then rebooted laptop for checking. Everything was ok and Windows booted and had access to SSD's data without problem. Please if you have any idea and any paid tool/solution let me know please. Just wanna make it un-frozen and without any password just like first day

Comment: I have no idea. This situation is completely new to me, so I can only go with what info you provided.